# Difference between "subsequently" and "consequently"?

Tags: construction, logic, semantics

When studying and reading course material in "softer" sciences that are descriptive the word "subsequently" appears in a way like "and subsequently" ...what does it mean, disctinct from "consequently" ?

Is the difference that "subsequently" doesn't imply a causality and the word "consequently" does? For instance A ⇒ B should read "A and consequently B" and in that case using the word "subsequently" is not false but it's not right since the word subsequently doesn't imply a causality which A ⇒ B does, so when talking about causality the we should use is "consequently"?

Comment: subsequence is to consequence as correlation is to causation

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're correct: *subsequently* doesn't imply causation.

> **subsequent**: Following in order or succession; coming or placed after, esp. immediately after.
>
> **consequent**: Following as an effect or result; resulting.

(Both definitions are from the Oxford English Dictionary.)

You might use *subsequently* to avoid the [*post hoc, ergo propter hoc*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc) fallacy.

Answer (score -1):

Think of it this way: consequent requires there to be a consequence or a cause that the writer is trying to address. While subsequent is used to show the different parts of a particular event in smaller increments or successions.